# What does the term 'hyperbolic model' mean?

Tags: terminology, non-linear-systems

I am reading [this non-linear discrete dynamical system paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0025-5564(92)90012-L). The authors mention the term [hyperbolic model](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=&as_epq=hyperbolic+model). What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it is related to hyperbolic [partial differential equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_partial_differential_equation).

Answer (score 0):

Example of a hyperbolic system, the first order wave equation: $ {\partial \underline{U} \over \partial t} + \underline{A} {\partial \underline{U} \over \partial x} = 0$

The term hyperbolic means that:

- The eigenvalues of the $m \times m$ Jacobian matrix ($\underline A $) are all real
- There is a corresponding set of $m$ linearly independent eigenvectors

This allows decomposition of the system into a linear combination of these eigenvectors, where the corresponding eigenvalues of $\underline{A}$ give the wave speeds.